# netplan yaml file apply error while setting up Bridge and Bonding port on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, netplan, network-bonding

I try to setup a bridge and bonding port on Ubuntu 18.04 server, got a error message:

```
/etc/netplan/00-netcfg.yaml:15:33: Error in network definition: unknown key 'interfaces'
                                interfaces:
                                ^
```

Anyone can help what's wrong?
the yaml file detail as:

```
network:
        bridges:
                br0:
                        addresses:
                                - 10.1.1.100/24
                        dhcp4: false
                        dhcp6: false
                        gateway4: 10.1.1.254
                        nameservers:
                                addresses:
                                        - 8.8.8.8
                                        - 8.8.4.4
                                search: []
                                interfaces:
                                        - bond0
                                bonds:
                                        bond0:
                                                interfaces:
                                                        - enp2s0f0
                                                        - enp2s0f1
                                                parameters:
                                                        mode: balance-rr
        ethernets:
                enp2s0f0:
                        addresses: []
                        dhcp4: false
                        dhcp6: false
                enp2s0f1:
                        addresses: []
                        dhcp4: false
                        dhcp6: false
```

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml shows that you have `interfaces` indented under `nameservers`.  The interface list is clearly not part of the nameserver configuration.  It needs to be indented so that it is in line with the other top-level properties of `br0`.

Your `bonds` section also needs to be indented at the same level as ethernets and bridges.

Answer (score 1):

Use this .yaml. Keep the EXACT same spacing and indentation...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0f0:
      addresses: []
    enp2s0f1:
      addresses: []
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
        - 10.1.1.100/24
      gateway4: 10.1.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      interfaces:
        - bond0
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - enp2s0f0
        - enp2s0f1
      parameters:
        mode: balance-rr
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`